# SimpleCursorAdapter keeps throwing error for API 10

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-support-library

My project has a minSDK of 10 and a target of 17. I've added `android-support-v4.jar` to the project build path by right-clicking on the `.jar` file and selecting "Build Path -> Add to Build Path". When I clean the project, the errors for `SimpleCursorAdapter` are gone. However when I try and run the activity, I get the following error:

> 01-05 23:42:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(483):
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.

Also, if I make changes to the activity I have to clean the project every time just to get rid of the error with `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

What am I missing here? Why isn't this working properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using the compatibility version of the class. Check your imports and make sure you are using this:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```