# Alternative of SimpleCursorAdapter in API8

Tags: android, api, simplecursoradapter

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.country_info,
            cursor, columns, to, 0);
```

SimpleCursorAdapter requires API11. What is alternative way to do this in API8?

Comment: @pskink Can you give link where I can take it or how to do it?

Comment: google for: android support library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179405/2255924)

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```

This line of code should be added. Collision with import SimpleCursorCollision may happen. In that case remove this line

```
import SimpleCursorAdapter;
```